# How to Write Custom Traces in WCF and See the Traces

Tags: c#, wcf, trace

I have a WCF service where I log activities using the Trace.Writeline() method. It has been working great but for some reason it has stopped working recently. Now I only have traces from "System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" and  "System.ServiceModel". I don't remember I have changed the configuration but somebody might have but I don't remember how it was used to be configured. Here is what I have now:

First, I have defined the following to log all the messages:

```
   <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
            logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
            logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="10000"
            maxSizeOfMessageToLog="1000000" />
            <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
</diagnostics>
```

I then defined the trace sources below and tell the TRACE class where the traces should be written:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traceListener"
                type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                initializeData="E:\Projects\Logs\serviceTraces.svclog" />                   
            </listeners>
        </source>
     <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messagelistener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="E:\Projects\Logs\MyServiceMsg.svclog">
        </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
         <listeners>
            <add name="textLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="E:\Projects\Logs\MyServiceCustomMsg.svclog" />
            <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
  </trace>  
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Since I am getting traces from "MyServiceMsg.svclog" and "MyServiceCustomMsg.svclog", I don't think it is a permission issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason. "Trace" was not turned on at build time. After a re-build with Trace turned on, my custom traces begin to show up!